# Clicking submit while dropdown menu is shown does not submit form in chrome, but does in IE

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, forms, cross-browser

I have a simple date range search form with a "advanced options" dropdown using bootstrap.  My problem is that when the user presses the submit button while the advanced dropdown is shown it has different behaviour across different browsers.
In IE the dropdown closes and form will get submitted.  In Chrome, the dropdown closes but I have to click the submit button a second time to get the form to submit.

If I intercept the button click event and submit manually then I can get away with one click in Chrome, but then the form submits twice in IE.

Is there any way to get a consistent behaviour across both browsers?

https://jsfiddle.net/joeykruger75/bv8dshu8/

```js
$('#date-range-box').daterangepicker({

  "startDate": "07/14/2017",
  "endDate": "07/20/2017"
});


$('.dropdown-menu').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation(); //This will prevent the event from bubbling up and close the dropdown when you type/click on text boxes.
});

$('#search-form').submit(function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  showMsg('submitted');
});

function showMsg(msg) {
  var options = {
    day: "2-digit",
    hour: "2-digit",
    minute: "2-digit",
    second: "2-digit",
    year: "numeric",
    month: "2-digit",
    useGrouping: "false"
  };
  var dateS = new Date().toLocaleString('en-GB', options);
  toastr.options.positionClass = "toast-bottom-right";
  toastr.info(msg + ' - ' + dateS, {
    "positionClass": "toast-bottom-right",
  });

}
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.dropdown.dropdown-lg .dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: -1px;
  padding: 6px 20px;
}

.input-group-btn .btn-group {
  display: flex !important;
}

.btn-group .btn {
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-left: -1px;
}

.btn-group .btn:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}

.btn-group .form-horizontal .btn[type="submit"] {
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}

.form-horizontal .form-group {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.form-group .form-control:last-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  #adv-search {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .dropdown.dropdown-lg {
    position: static !important;
  }
  .dropdown.dropdown-lg .dropdown-menu {
    min-width: 400px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>


<form name="myform" id="search-form" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="input-group" id="adv-search">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for snippets" id="date-range-box" />
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
              <div class="dropdown dropdown-lg">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Advanced <span class="caret"></span></button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="filter">Location</label>
                    <select class="form-control">
                                            <option value="0" selected>All Locations</option>
                                            <option value="1">Location #1</option>
                                            <option value="2">Location #2</option>
                                            <option value="3">Location #3</option>
                                            <option value="4">Location #4</option>
                                        </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="filter">Product</label>
                    <select class="form-control">
                                            <option value="0" selected>All Products</option>
                                            <option value="1">Product #1</option>
                                            <option value="2">Product #2</option>
                                            <option value="3">Product #3</option>
                                            <option value="4">Product #4</option>
                                            <option value="4">Product #5</option>
                                        </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="contain">Customer Ref</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I figured out that there is a hidden div that gets displayed in chrome when the dropdown is displayed with a class of "dropdown-backdrop" and z-index of 990.   Strangely, this div is nowhere to be seen in IE, but it mean that the search button is not actually being clicked.  if I add the following CSS then the problem is solved.   Have not found any side-effects so far:

`.dropdown-backdrop {
    display: none;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try the `return false` option instead `ev.preventDefault()`

https://subinsb.com/jquery-return-false-vs-preventdefault/